# Auto download of Artwork and Lyrics for itunes on windows

Tags: itunes

I run Itunes on a Windows 7 machine. I know there are softwares to download and fix artwork and lyrics in Itunes on Mac. But I couldn't find a good one on Windows. Which software do you suggest? I found AutoLryrix to be decent, but its art work isn't good.

I used to run Curator on Mac and it used to update my itunes library with good high resolution pictures.